# Angular filter of array of objects by object

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

In the below code, `console.log($scope.gradeC.title);` shows the correct output; however the next console line does not show the expected output. I do not understand this behaviour. Any suggestions/pointers would help me to understand this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp=angular.module("myApp", []);
            myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter)
            {

                console.log("Inside controller");

                  $scope.results = {
                    year:2013,
                    subjects:[
                      {title:'English',grade:'A'},
                      {title:'Maths',grade:'A'},
                      {title:'Science',grade:'B'},
                      {title:'Geography',grade:'C'}
                    ]
                  };                
                  console.log($scope.results);
                  $scope.gradeC = $filter('filter')($scope.results.subjects, {grade: 'B'})[0];
                    console.log($scope.gradeC.title);
                    console.log(($scope.results.subjects|{grade: 'B'})[0].title);
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <h4>Printing div</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do u want to call the filter on the subject property?

Comment: "*shows the correct output*" - which is ?

Comment: Correct output is Geography which is the title of grade C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use `|` in controller to filter arrays.

```
$scope.gradeC = $filter('filter')($scope.results.subjects, {grade: 'C'})[0];

console.log($scope.gradeC);
```

or

```
console.log($filter('filter')($scope.results.subjects, {grade: 'C'})[0].title);
```

Comment: Thanks. in the filter array, do we not need to wrap both key and value in double quotes?

Comment: we wrap the value in quotes if it's a string `{grade : 'C'}` like C is a string value in this case.

Comment: Thanks. if my results is as follows:   
    
$scope.results = [{ "name":"John", "age":"30", "city":"New York"},{ "name":"John1", "age":"31", "city":"New York"},{ "name":"John2", "age":"32", "city":"New York"}, { "name":"John3", "age":"", "city":"New York"},];

i am expecting the code console.log($filter('filter')($scope.results, {age: ''})[0].name); to return John3. But it returns John.

Can you please let me know why $filter('filter')($scope.results, {age: ''} is returning entire array? Thanks in advance.